# Pandas: Apply search function

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reproduce some [neat forest plots](http://blog.applied.ai/bayesian-inference-with-pymc3-part-3/) on my own data. However, I'm stuck at this function, and can't for the life of me figure out what its supposed to do.

I am trying to make the following code work on my data:

```
def create_smry(trc, data, pname='subject'):
    ''' Conv fn: create trace summary for sorted forestplot '''

    dfsm = pm.df_summary(trc).reset_index()
    dfsm.rename(columns={'index':'featval'}, inplace=True)

    print(dfsm.head(n=5))

    dfsm = dfsm.loc[dfsm['featval'].apply(
        lambda x: re.search('{}__[0-9]+'.format(pname), x) is not None)]

    dfsm.set_index(dfs[pname].unique(), inplace=True)
    dfsm.sort('mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    dfsm['ypos'] = np.arange(len(dfsm))

    return dfsm
```

where the print returns:

```
  featval      mean        sd  mc_error   hpd_2.5  hpd_97.5
0    mu_a -0.008913  0.011715  0.000613 -0.029139  0.014329
1    mu_b  0.003252  0.000271  0.000015  0.002698  0.003765
2    a__0 -0.065255  0.024315  0.001168 -0.113708 -0.018885
3    a__1 -0.081748  0.023247  0.001114 -0.124560 -0.036777
4    a__2  0.025326  0.021661  0.001024 -0.019744  0.065263
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-2465af1d68b8> in <module>()
----> 1 dfsm_unpl_mfr = create_smry(hierarchical_trace[-333:], data, 'subject')
      2 custom_forestplot(dfsm_unpl_mfr)

<ipython-input-123-5f6828d6cf8e> in create_smry(trc, data, pname)
      8 
      9     dfsm = dfsm.loc[dfsm['featval'].apply(
---> 10         lambda x: re.search('{}__[0-9]+'.format(pname), x) is not None)]
     11 
     12     dfsm.set_index(dfs[pname].unique(), inplace=True)

~/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66645)()

<ipython-input-123-5f6828d6cf8e> in <lambda>(x)
      8 
      9     dfsm = dfsm.loc[dfsm['featval'].apply(
---> 10         lambda x: re.search('{}__[0-9]+'.format(pname), x) is not None)]
     11 
     12     dfsm.set_index(dfs[pname].unique(), inplace=True)

NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

1. **I cant figure out what re.search is, since re is not a df.**
2. **What does `{}__[0-9]+` mean in this context?**

Since the input is quite complicated, I can't provide a minimal working example.

***After import of regex:***

```
import re

def create_smry(trc, data, pname='subject'):
    ''' Conv fn: create trace summary for sorted forestplot '''

    dfsm = pm.df_summary(trc).reset_index()
    dfsm.rename(columns={'index':'featval'}, inplace=True)

    print(dfsm.head(n=10))

    dfsm = dfsm.loc[dfsm['featval'].apply(
        lambda x: re.search('{}__[0-90]+'.format(pname), x) is not None)]

    print(dfsm.head(n=10))

    dfsm.set_index(data[pname].unique(), inplace=True)
    dfsm.sort_values('mean', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    dfsm['ypos'] = np.arange(len(dfsm))

    print(dfsm.head(n=15))

    return dfsm
```

which returns

```
  featval      mean        sd  mc_error   hpd_2.5  hpd_97.5
0   b0_mu -0.022521  0.010266  0.000597 -0.042222 -0.003072
1   b1_mu  0.003220  0.000256  0.000014  0.002742  0.003700
2   b2_mu  0.024366  0.005288  0.000292  0.014786  0.035139
3   b3_mu  0.008563  0.004393  0.000243  0.000634  0.017385
4   b0__0 -0.078060  0.025093  0.001208 -0.121480 -0.024921
5   b0__1 -0.097636  0.024500  0.001413 -0.144801 -0.052600
6   b0__2  0.009216  0.024381  0.001229 -0.038927  0.052254
7   b0__3  0.024541  0.025525  0.001399 -0.025824  0.070295
8   b0__4 -0.069331  0.020887  0.001057 -0.106392 -0.024169
9   b0__5 -0.065629  0.024787  0.001178 -0.111582 -0.019849
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [featval, mean, sd, mc_error, hpd_2.5, hpd_97.5]
Index: []
```

If I block out the re.search and simply plot (also dont try to change the index, I get a plot:

[image]

However, re.search was not employed correctly, so all y-values from trc fra plotted.

**EDIT**: Ended up using

```
dfsm['featidx'] = dfsm['featval'].apply(lambda x: any(pd.Series(x).str.contains(feat)))
```

since I could not figure out regex.

Comment: Did you call `import re`? The regex library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I cant figure out what re.search is, since re is not a df.`

`re` is a regex library to perform regex actions on a string. You need to call `import re` in the header or python file to use it.

`What does {}__[0-9]+ mean in this context?`

It is a regex pattern, `re.search` says, scan through string looking for a location where this regular expression (`{}__[0-9]+`) produces a match, and return a corresponding match object .

For more info about the library : 
'[Regex Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)'

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer! I've changed the regex expression to `dfsm = dfsm.loc[dfsm['featval'].apply(lambda x: re.search('{}__[0-90]+'.format(pname), x) is not None)]`. However, this returns an empty dataframe. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Glad to help @TMorville.